# Why are my for loops not working in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to make a chess variation, and to make the squares for the board, I am trying to loop through the files and ranks, and adding the square to an array, as well as logging that a colored square was made. I get the same two errors for each loop.
The errors are:
"Assets\Scripts\BoardManager.cs(17,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
Assets\Scripts\BoardManager.cs(17,36): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Here is the code:

`    using System;
using UnityEngine;

```
public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Color whiteSquare = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
    public Color blackSquare = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Square[] squares = new Square[36];
        int squareNumTemp = 1;
        Color squareColorTemp;

        for (int rank = 1; rank++; rank <= 6)
        {
            for (int file = 1; (int)file++; file <= 6)
            {
                if ((file + rank) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    squareColorTemp = blackSquare;
                    Debug.Log("Black square made");
                } else 
                {
                    squareColorTemp = blackSquare;
                    Debug.Log("White square made");
                }
                squares[squareNumTemp] = new Square(squareNumTemp, squareColorTemp);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

class Square
{
    public int squareNum;
    public Color squareColor;

    public Square (int numIn, Color colorIn)
    {
        this.squareNum = numIn;
        this.squareColor = colorIn;
    }
}`
```

I tried to make the file and rank variables integers using (int) but that did not work. I also cannot decipher what the second error means.

Comment: Instead of `for (int rank = 1; rank++; rank <= 6)` you probably want `for (int rank = 1; rank <= 6; rank++)` Same for the other loop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/branches-and-loops-local#work-with-the-for-loop

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I didn't see that, thank you! That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is formed wrong.
It is expecting a `condition` and not `int` (you're returning integer with `rank++`)

```
for (int rank = 1; rank <= 6; rank++)
{
    for (int file = 1; file <= 6; file++)
    {
```

> "Assets\Scripts\BoardManager.cs(17,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Error CS0029 is [type conversion error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029)

Error CS0201 is [invalid statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201)

[for loops in C#](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php)
You can see from the W3 website, statement 2 defines the condition (`bool`) and statement 3 is the one executed every loop (`rank++`)

So just turning those two around fixes your issue